# Error: Warning: Middleware for RTK-Query API at reducerPath "api" has not been added to the store - but it has been added

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, next.js

So I am migrating my application to NextJS and I have the following store configuration. It's a little messy right now as I'll be cleaning up everything/reducing duplicated code once I've got it all working.

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import {
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from 'redux-persist';
import expireReducer from 'redux-persist-expire';
import { API } from 'utils/RTKAPI';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import { createOrSyncSettings } from 'controllers/SettingsController';
import { syncWords } from 'controllers/WordController';
import { syncSentences } from 'controllers/SentenceController';
import { syncBookmarks } from 'controllers/BookmarkController';
import { syncReadArticles } from 'controllers/ReadArticleController';
import rootSaga from 'reducers/sagas/index';
import moment from 'moment';
import { createWrapper, HYDRATE } from 'next-redux-wrapper';
import rootReducer from 'reducers/rootReducer';


const makeStore = () => {
  const SSR = typeof window === 'undefined';
  if (SSR) {

    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

    const store = configureStore({
      middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware({
          serializableCheck: {
            ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
          },
        }).concat(
          loggerMiddleware,
          promiseMiddleware,
          sagaMiddleware,
          syncMiddleware,
          API.middleware
        ),
      reducer: rootReducer(),
    });
    sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
    return store;
  } else {
    const { persistStore, persistReducer } = require('redux-persist');
    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

    const persistConfig = {
      key: 'root',
      storage: AsyncStorage,
      blacklist: [API.reducerPath, 'router', 'sidebar', 'currentchar'],
      transforms: [
        expireReducer('date', {
          expireSeconds: 86400,
          expiredState: {
            end_date: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            start_date: '2021-07-04',
          },
          autoExpire: true,
        }),
      ],
    };

    const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer());
    const store = configureStore({
      middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware({
          serializableCheck: {
            ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
          },
        }).concat(
          loggerMiddleware,
          promiseMiddleware,
          sagaMiddleware,
          syncMiddleware,
          API.middleware
        ),
      reducer: persistedReducer,
    });

    sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

    store.__persistor = persistStore(store); // Necessary hack

    return store;
  }
};

export const wrapper = createWrapper(makeStore);

async function callSync(store) {
  const storeState = await store.getState();
  const profile = storeState.profile;
  if (profile !== null) {
    createOrSyncSettings(profile.id);
    syncWords(profile);
    syncSentences(profile);
    syncBookmarks(profile);
    syncReadArticles(profile);
  }
}

const loggerMiddleware = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
  next(action);
};

function promiseMiddleware({ dispatch }) {
  function isPromise(val) {
    return val && typeof val.then === 'function';
  }

  return (next) => (action) => {
    return isPromise(action.payload)
      ? action.payload.then(
          (result) => dispatch({ ...action, payload: result }),
          (error) => dispatch({ ...action, payload: error, error: true })
        )
      : next(action);
  };
}

const syncMiddleware = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
  next(action);
  if (action.type === 'persist/REHYDRATE') {
    callSync(store);
  }
};
```

My rootReducer is pretty standard too:

```
export default () =>
  combineReducers({
    [API.reducerPath]: API.reducer,
    categories,
    profile,
    ...
```

Yet despite my configuration, I keep getting this error:

```
Error: Warning: Middleware for RTK-Query API at reducerPath "api" has not been added to the store.
You must add the middleware for RTK-Query to function correctly!
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? As far as I can tell, my reducerPath **has** been added to the store.

A similar store configuration worked just fine in a previous iteration of my app, that did not use NextJS, so I am wondering what is causing the issue now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hand-written Redux `syncMiddleware`  is broken.  It doesn't return the result of `next(action)`.  That means that if a *later* middleware tries to return a value, that later return result gets thrown away and will never be returned from `dispatch`.

The RTKQ configuration check relies on dispatching a special action that is intercepted by the RTKQ middleware and returning a matching result.  Since your middleware is throwing away that result, the UI layer concludes that the RTKQ middleware was not actually added correctly.  (And in a sense, it wasn't!)

Comment: So I'd just need to return next(action) and it would all be fine?

Comment: Tried adding this to the bottom of my syncMiddleware:

  return next(action);

Still seeing the same error

Comment: Looks like `loggerMiddleware` has the same problem.  If you make sure that _every_ middleware is updated to at some point return the result of `next(action)`, does this still happen?

Comment: Yep, that does seem to have fixed the problem. Weird. I've had this same middleware for the entire life of my application and it hasn't ever caused this issue before, only upon migration to Next. I'm going to read the docs on how to write better middleware. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After develop every Api slice you should put them inside of your middleware store.

```js
const middlewares = (getDefaultMiddleware: CurriedGetDefaultMiddleware) =>
  getDefaultMiddleware().concat([
    authApiSlice.middleware,
    rtkQueryErrorLogger,
    ...
  ]);
```

Put middlewares into middleware parameter in `configureStore()`.